# Why runnable task can't be interrupted with AtomicBoolean flag?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have next task

```
public class QuittableTask implements Runnable {
  final int id;

  public QuittableTask(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

  public void quit() {
  System.out.println("Quite " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     running.set(false);
  }

  @Override
   public void run() {
    while (running.get()) {        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        new Nap(0.1);
    }
    System.out.print(id + " ");  
   }
```

I run a lot of tasks using

```
public class QuittingTasks {
  public static final int COUNT = 1500;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<QuittableTask> tasks =
            IntStream.range(1, COUNT)
                    .mapToObj(QuittableTask::new)
                    .peek(es::execute)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    tasks.forEach(QuittableTask::quit);
    es.shutdown();
}
```

When i use **COUNT < 10000** everything is ok. All threads are being terminated. Programm finishes in 2 seconds.

But when i use **COUNT > 100001** method **quite** can't be reached and my programm goes to infinite loop. I don't understand such behaviour. Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: Stream peek is a debugging method and is open to side effects. Can you better completely build the List, then loop over to execute, then loop over to quit? (in other words, don't try to make the stream to build and execute withing the same chain) That might help

Comment: You're using a cached thread pool which will create threads on demand. When `COUNT > 100_001` you are creating 100,001+ threads.

Comment: But why is programm continuing working? why it is not exited with error?

Comment: I tried something similar on my computer and it took a very long time to actually `execute` the tasks. In fact, I never finished scheduling all the tasks because creating that many threads was hogging my CPU and freezing my computer—so I killed the process. Are you sure your program is even reaching the `QuittableTask::quit` call in a timely manner?

Comment: Yes, i analized logs. with huge COUNT quite never calls

Comment: Then you're either encountering an exception/error, as [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724839/6395627) demonstrates, or your program is simply taking a long time to schedule each task and you only think it's hanging.

Comment: The other option is your main thread is starving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely on logs (adding some logs on your code) you can see that when the program is generating `OutOfMemoryError`. And the error looks like below:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.java8.demo.Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

That means you are getting OutOfMemory when you try to call `quit` on all the task but as the error occurs it never gets executed, as a result of your boolean flag never set to false. And other thread keeps running.

You can notice that out of memory occurs as VM unable to create the native thread.Now you are using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`. So your thread pools max size can be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but before reaching that value your VM unable to create new thread. I have changed the executor to FixTheradPool like `ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);`. It works fine with your higher `COUNT` value as it will create only 8 thread.

I have put a `try-catch` block to trace the exception like below. Also, I forcefully exit the VM by calling System#exit to trace the logs on my console.

```
try {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<QuittableTask> tasks = IntStream.range(1, COUNT).mapToObj(QuittableTask::new).peek(es::execute)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    tasks.forEach(QuittableTask::quit);
    es.shutdown();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @ArtyomKarnov I have edited my answer and added the code to trace the error. Please take a look at the updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add on to @AmitBera's answer - `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` creates a practically unbounded thread pool (see the explanation by the "Queueing" section in [the API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)). So every new `QuittingTask` instance is handed off to a new thread and goes into execution immediately.

At some point the number of `QuittingTask` instances and new thread instances, especially the new thread instances, grow out of memory. That "some point" is sensitive to the JVM's memory configuration. You happen to get 10001 in yours. When I run this I run out at 4073.